# Issue in migrating asp.net application to Microsoft Edge (Version 91.0.864.70 (Official build) (64-bit))

Tags: asp.net, single-sign-on, microsoft-edge

In my organisation we have decided to make compatible a asp.net application with SSO (Single Sign-On) so it works for Microsoft Edge.
We removed all inline style and script to external files.
When we debug this application without SSO it works perfectly in Internet Explorer and Edge.
However when we deploy in server with SSO we are running into issues in Edge browser (It works seamlessly in IE)
In every postback click/ page redirection the webpage gets redirected to Login page and since all Session variables remain intact the page comes back to the default url we have given in SSO.
Further more, this issue does not happen consistently with all postback operations/ page redirection so we are not able to establish a pattern.
Note: This application with inline style and script with the expanded Content Security Provider works perfectly in Microsoft Edge ("default-src 'self' script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'")

Comment: According to your description, I am afraid I cannot determine your problem. Have you tested it in other browsers? Such as Chrome or Edge Canary. And during your test, did you try to track the network flow using fiddler? Or is there any error message in the browser console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue had been with forms authentication. Once we removed the below from web.config the redirection issue didn't occur.

```
    <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms name=".ASPXAUTH" protection="All" timeout="120" 
     slidingExpiration="true" requireSSL="false"/>
    </authentication>
```

Got the solution from- https://forums.iis.net/t/1186644.aspx

Comment: Congratulations! Thanks for posting the solution for this issue. You can mark your answer as an accepted answer after 48 hrs, when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.